# Postgresql 12 Replication Fail

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I'm trying to replicate database server which still running/active accepting requests from users such as inserting and updating.

I ran this command mentioned below to start copying my primary server to replication server:

```
 root@replica:~#sudo -u postgres pg_basebackup -h [PRIMARY_IP] -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -U replication -P -v
```

The backup process had no error and finished, but I encounter error as follows when trying to start postgresql server.

`root@replica:~#tail /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log`

```
2020-10-03 01:15:12.198 UTC [552567] FATAL:  database system identifier differs between the primary and standby
2020-10-03 01:15:12.198 UTC [552567] DETAIL:  The primary's identifier is 6805716485467355646, the standby's identifier is 6875279138564418280.
2020-10-03 01:15:17.204 UTC [552568] FATAL:  database system identifier differs between the primary and standby
2020-10-03 01:15:17.204 UTC [552568] DETAIL:  The primary's identifier is 6805716485467355646, the standby's identifier is 6875279138564418280.
2020-10-03 01:15:22.207 UTC [552570] FATAL:  database system identifier differs between the primary and standby
2020-10-03 01:15:22.207 UTC [552570] DETAIL:  The primary's identifier is 6805716485467355646, the standby's identifier is 6875279138564418280.
2020-10-03 01:15:27.212 UTC [552579] FATAL:  database system identifier differs between the primary and standby
2020-10-03 01:15:27.212 UTC [552579] DETAIL:  The primary's identifier is 6805716485467355646, the standby's identifier is 6875279138564418280.
2020-10-03 01:15:32.216 UTC [552581] FATAL:  database system identifier differs between the primary and standby
2020-10-03 01:15:32.216 UTC [552581] DETAIL:  The primary's identifier is 6805716485467355646, the standby's identifier is 6875279138564418280.
```

Any one have idea how to fix this things without trying `pg_basebackup` process again? since it took time and bandwidth for me.

Comment: I see you didn't use -R with pg_basebackup.  So how did you set up streaming?  The simplest explanation is that you did it wrong, pointing replication to a different server than the backup was taken from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I never did it replication before. I follow @jjanes suggestion, I delete my previous copy and then ran:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_basebackup -h [PRIMARY_IP] -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -U replication -P -v -R -X stream -C -S pgbackup1
```

And its working.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in context of Postgres 14.

I faced same error while bringing up a standby in streaming replication mode. In my case, these were the steps to reproduce this error:

1. Brought up an empty standby server.
2. All required configs were already in place on the standby to enable streaming replication.
3. Take back from standby with `pg_basebackup` utility as:
   `pg_basebackup -D /backup -F t -P -v -U replicator -X stream -w --no-password`
4. Back up got successfully created. But, note that, in the above command, the `-h` option was left out, as a result, the back up got taken from the standby instead of the primary.
5. Stop the stand-by and clear its data directory.
6. Extract the /backup/base.tar  to the empty standby data directory.
7. Create an empty standby.signal in the standby data directory.
8. Restart standby.
9. The standby fails to start with `database system identifier differs between the primary and standby`.
10. Execute step 3 with an additional `-h` option specifying the primary host.
11. Repeat step 4 to 8.
12. The standby comes up without error.

Also, it's important to note that the standby data directory gets fully replaced from the back up. The same error may re-appear, if standby data directory is not fully replaced from the backup.